# Trying to emulate CS:GO in wine, but my PC is not having any of it

Tags: games, crash, emulation, ubuntu-emulator

So, I was having problems with CS today; the game was being jittery and weird. People said that emulating it will make it much smoother. I emulated steam, downloaded CS, installed a version of Direct X whilst launching as it made me do so (I knew it was not going to end well) and the game instantly crashed. Then my res was changed for some reason and I had to restart my PC in order to do anything.

This might sound vague, but I really don't know what the problem is. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your graphics card model?

Comment: I'm intergrated. Need a new PC soon. Intel Sandy Bridge if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem with doom3 compiled from source.  I found on a forum that killing pulseaudio solved the problem.  It might be the same problem.  Try killing pulse and seeing if that solves your problem.  CS can run natively, so it should use ALSA if nothing else is available.

Be careful with killing pulse though.  At one point, it put my sound card in an inconsistent state, and it didn't work at all for a while.  I don't remember how I fixed it.

Comment: Sounds like a bizarre fix, will try this though

Comment: It is a quite bizarre fix, but it worked at least once.

Comment: Didn't work, still can't properly launch the game.

Comment: I'll just leave it there until you get a working answer so people can see you tried it and delete it when you get an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Global Offensive, it is now available by Steam for Linux platform too. Just check it.

I use **Steam** on Linux and play "*Counter Strike Global Offensive*" without using wine or any other emulater.

Bonus : You can now play many other games on Linux without using any emulator. Search for your favorites and explore the new ones on Steam For Linux. :)